# How to add custom font in DOM pdf in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom, pdf, fonts, dom

I have tried to add font using below code in head tag of html but it is not working.

DOM PDF is showing it's default font. But i want to show custom fonts as per my website. So tried below code

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3aCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have added particular font folder in media path. After that we have called it in head tag.

Below code is properly working.

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
$mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Barlow';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            src: url(<?= $mediaUrl ?>font/Barlow-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'BarlowBold';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            src: url(<?= $mediaUrl ?>font/Barlow-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'BarlowSemiBold';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            src: url(<?= $mediaUrl ?>font/Barlow-SemiBold.ttf) format('truetype');
        }

        body { font-family: 'Barlow'; }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <header>
        Write header content here    
    </header>

    <footer>
        Write footer content here
    </footer>
    <div class="productpdf-sec">
        Write other content
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```